# DataGridViewComboBoxCell show row value as default

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, default, datagridviewcomboboxcell

im want put a `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` in a specific column for any rows i have in my `DataGridView`.
Now i have a problem... I would like to show a default value in that specific columns where i had put a `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`, but there is nothing shown..

```
String[] options = new String[] {"On", "Off" };

for(int i = 0; i< rows.Count; i++)
{
     // lets say one row looks like this {"1","On"}, {"2", "Off"}
     MydataGridView.Rows.Add(rows[i]);

     DataGridViewComboBoxCell MyComboBox= new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
     MyComboBox.Items.AddRange(options);

     MydataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1] = MyComboBox;

}
```

I would like to show my added rows as default, before I can select a `{"On","Off"}` state via `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`.

I hope it was clearly enough. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this ([`DataGridView.CellFormatting Event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?view=netframework-4.7.2)):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MydataGridView.CellFormatting += MydataGridView_CellFormatting;
}

private void MydataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1) //Index of your DataGridViewComboBoxCell 
    {
        e.Value = "yourDefaultValue";
    }
}
```

Also I have seen the following event as well, that is also used to set the default value ([`DataGridView.DefaultValuesNeeded Event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.defaultvaluesneeded?view=netframework-4.7.2)):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MydataGridView.DefaultValuesNeeded += MydataGridView_DefaultValuesNeeded;
}

private void MydataGridView_DefaultValuesNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[1].Value = "yourDefaultValue";
}
```

Comment: oh haha :D its a nice property. it works fine, thank you :) its a better way than i solved it by myself.